# Showing ExpandItem slowly

Tags: java, swt

I am using SWT `ExpandBar` in my application. Now I have got one requirement that when I click
the `ExpandBar`, I wanted to show the item in a very slower manner.

That means some kind of
animation to the expand bar. Similar to jQuery. Currently when I click the `ExpandBar`, immediately it shows the contents which is the
default behaviour. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid this is not possible.

The `ExpandBar` like all other stock SWT widgets is implemented by the native platform you are running on. And the platform defines how the `ExpandItem` appears and behaves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to achieve the same behaviour somehow through Any other API  like Nebula,etc?